# Minesweeper implementation output seems ok but fails UVa Judge tests

Tags: java

The Input

The input will consist of an arbitrary number of fields. The first line of each field contains two integers n and m (0 < n,m <= 100) which stands for the number of lines and columns of the field respectively. The next n lines contains exactly m characters and represent the field. Each safe square is represented by an "." character (without the quotes) and each mine square is represented by an "*" character (also without the quotes). The first field line where n = m = 0 represents the end of input and should not be processed.

The Output

For each field, you must print the following message in a line alone:

Field #x:
Where x stands for the number of the field (starting from 1). The next n lines should contain the field with the "." characters replaced by the number of adjacent mines to that square. There must be an empty line between field outputs.

Sample Input

```
4 4

*...

....

.*..

....

3 5

**...

.....

.*...

0 0
```

Sample Output

```
Field #1:

*100

2210

1*10

1110


Field #2:

**100

33200

1*100
```

I get the correct output for the given inputs.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //field size
        int n, m;
        //string to hold a row of a minesweeper board
        String line;
        //array to hold all the minesweeper boards entered
        ArrayList<char[][]> allBoards = new ArrayList<char[][]>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //get the field size
        n = scan.nextInt();
        m = scan.nextInt();

        //keep going until n=0 and m=0
        while ((n+m)!=0) {

            //create the minesweeper board
            //the field sizes are 2 spaces bigger to prevent error checking 
            //at the edges of the minesweeper board            
            char[][] board = new char[n + 2][m + 2];

            //fill the appropriate spaces with the mines '*' and blank spaces '.'
            for (int row = 1; row < board.length - 1; row++) {
                line = scan.next();
                for (int col = 1; col < board[0].length - 1; col++) {
                    board[row][col] = line.charAt(col - 1);
                }
            }

            //add the current minesweeper board to the array
            allBoards.add(board);

            //get new field size
            n = scan.nextInt();
            m = scan.nextInt();
        }

        printResults(allBoards);
    }

    //function to find out how many mines are around a certain position
    //check all positions surrounding the current one.
    public static int getMines(char[][] board, int row, int col) {
        int nMines = 0;

        if (board[row - 1][col - 1] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row - 1][col] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row - 1][col + 1] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row][col - 1] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row][col + 1] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row + 1][col - 1] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row + 1][col] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        if (board[row + 1][col + 1] == '*') {
            nMines++;
        }

        return nMines;
    }

    //print the results
    private static void printResults(ArrayList<char[][]> allBoards) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= allBoards.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Field #" + i + ":");
            for (int row = 1; row < allBoards.get(i - 1).length - 1; row++) {
                for (int col = 1; col < allBoards.get(i - 1)[0].length - 1; col++) {
                    if (allBoards.get(i - 1)[row][col] != '*') {
                        System.out.print(getMines(allBoards.get(i - 1), row, col));
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm so whats the problem again?

Comment: If this question is not closed, make sure you come up with a better title. The one you are using ("UVa Online Judge submission") is the same as "Please help!".

Comment: the problem is that after i submit it i get an email from UVa Judge saying i have the wrong answer...i just need a fresh pair of eyes to help me understand where the problem might be.

Comment: i changed the title...is that any better...? i had no idea what to change it to, lol.

Comment: try something in the lines of: Minesweeper implementation output seems ok but fails UVa Judge tests

Comment: @linda - Try adding an empty line at the end.

Comment: Does the checker give any information at all about what it doesn't like?  For example, the output might be OK but the checker might not like the memory consumption (from the information given, there's no reason to keep all the minefields - you can read in a minefield, print out its result, then throw that minefield away and process the next one by reading it in and so on until you hit the "0 0" end-of-data marker).

Comment: @MichaelBurr the checker does not give any info about what it doesn't like, which makes error checking a little difficult, especially when all seems to work fine.  As far as memory consumption, UVa judge doesn't say anything, the only thing is a time limit of 3 seconds.  Also i did as you said before (read a minefield, then output) but that's not the format they want.

Comment: It looks like your program prints an empty line after all the boards are printed. The assignment says that "There must be an empty line between field outputs", but might not want an empty line after the last field output. Try changing the program so that last empty line isn't output (an appropriate `if` statement can be added to prevent it).

Comment: @MichaelBurr thank you very much!  i did put an if statement there to guard from the last extra line and it worked!! so happy!  this question is now solved :)